# comment multiple lines in cmake at one go, something like #if 0 #endif

Tags: comments, cmake

This may be the issue with each script in Linux/Unix like OS

Q Is there a way to comment multiple lines at one go ? Something like below which **does NOT work** ( and also does not throw any error)

> #if 0
>       INCLUDE(FindPkgConfig)
>
> ```
> include_directories(/usr/local/include/gstreamer-0.10)
> include_directories(/usr/local/include/gstreamer-0.10/gst)
> include_directories(/usr/include/glib-2.0)
> include_directories(/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib)
> include_directories(/usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject)
> include_directories(/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include)
> include_directories(/usr/include/libxml2)
> ```
>
> #endif

We can obviously do it adding "#" at start of each line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In cmake, your `if` statement requires parentheses to operate, i.e.,

> ```
> if(0)
>     Command1(arg1)
> endif(0)
> ```

Also, `#if` does not work as a cmake statement.

Comment: I think `if(0)` should be matched by a corresponding `endif(0)`, otherwise I expect a warning from cmake.

Comment: No, there is no such warning. I checked

Comment: Such a warning or lack thereof may depend on the version of cmake.  In any case, it doesn't hurt to include the `endif(0)` for both clarity and to ensure that you don't comment out more of the code than you intend to.

Answer (score 3):

Apart the correct answer of abiessu, you can use an editor which allows you to comment multiple lines (a selection) in one go. For example, under Windows Notepad++ allows that by pressing ctrl+Q. It's always advisable to use an editor that "knows the language in which you are writing". CMake is a language on his own.